# Cannot read map from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am using map in one of my table as below:

```
media map<UUID, frozen<map<int, varchar>>>
```

Alhough I was able to successfully insert/update into this map, couldn't read from it.

I am using datastax java driver 3.0.0

So far I have tried this:

```
 Map<UUID, Map> media = row.getMap("media", UUID.class, Map.class);
```

But this line gives below exception:

```
 com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [map<int, varchar> <-> java.util.Map]
```

How can I read from this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `GettableByNameData.getMap(String, Class, Class)` method. Instead of that, to get complex data type like `Map`, you can use `GettableByNameData.getMap(String, TypeToken, TypeToken)` method.

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;

TypeToken uuidToken = new TypeToken<UUID>() {};
TypeToken mapToken = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, String>>() {};

Map<UUID, Map<Integer, String>> media = row.getMap("media", uuidToken, mapToken);
```